# What does that manipulation on pointer *this

Tags: c++, pointers, this

I want rewrite that small class to function but can't uderstand its logic.

That code:

```
class TE32ImageUids
{
public:
    TE32ImageUids(uint32_t aUid1, uint32_t aUid2, uint32_t aUid3);
    uint32_t Check();
private:
    uint32_t iUids[KMaxCheckedUid] = {0};
    uint32_t iCheck=0;
};

TE32ImageUids::TE32ImageUids(uint32_t aUid1, uint32_t aUid2, uint32_t aUid3)
{
   iUids[0]=aUid1;
   iUids[1]=aUid2;
   iUids[2]=aUid3;
}

uint32_t TE32ImageUids::Check()
{
    return ((checkSum(((uint8_t*)this)+1)<<16)|checkSum(this));
}
```

I wish to rewrite as function:

```
uint32_t GetUidChecksum(uint32_t aUid1, uint32_t aUid2, uint32_t aUid3)
{
    return checksum;
}
```

but think don't understand what happend in `return ((checkSum(((uint8_t*)this)+1)<<16)|checkSum(this));`

`(uint8_t*)this` treats `*this` as char array. `((uint8_t*)this)+1)` looks like second element in that array. But what hold *this? Data members first? Maybe function pointers?

Comment: @user463035818 C++ is case-sensitive, so `checksum` and `checkSum` refer to two different things.

Comment: ... ok then what is `checkSum` ?

Comment: There is not enough info to help.

Comment: The code is essentially doing `return (checkSum(&iUids[1]) << 16)  | checkSum(iUids);`  It calculates a 16bit checksum starting at the 2nd byte of `iUids`, shifts that checksum 16 bits to the left, and then appends a second 16bit checksum starting at the 1st byte of `iUids`.  Now, why it is getting the checksum from `iUids` the way it is, there is no way to know from this code. We would have to see the actual implementation of the `checkSum()` function

Comment: @user463035818, that function calculate checksum. How checkSum works irrelevant. `return checksum;` is pseudocode and means
return some checksummed value.

@RemyLebeau, are you sure about `(checkSum(&iUids[1]) << 16) | checkSum(iUids);`

Answer (score 0):

Broken down a bit:
`return ((checkSum(((uint8_t*)this)+1)<<16)|checkSum(this));`

`(uint8_t*)this` is still a pointer to the location of the current object, but the data is now interpreted as an 8-bit unsigned integer. `((uint8_t*)this)+1` basically adds one to `this` (interpreted as an unsigned 8-bit integer), giving a pointer to the second byte of the object. The checksum of that is then left-bitshifted 16 places and bitwise-ORed with the checksum of the pointer to the first byte of `this`. If `checkSum` returns a 16-bit number, then basically you are getting the checksum of the address of the second byte of the object followed by the checksum of the address of the first byte of the object. It might be clearer to see it written this way:

`return (checkSum(&((uint8_t*) this)[1]) << 16) | checkSum(&((uint8_t*) this)[0]);`

Comment: I want get rid from TE32ImageUids and staff with `this` too. But you rewritin is clear and very good.